# Webpack doesn't respect import order

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

We are currently working with Webpack and React using Bootstrap for the design and a custom CSS/SASS that overrides some of bootstraps styles.

On a simple HTML page we use:

```
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="./../../css/creative.css?v=1.9" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

Our style overrides bootstrap for example our `<hr>`

the one shown is the one defined in our `creative.css`

```
hr {
  max-width: 50px;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: #F05F40;
}
```

However when I move the design to the project using react and webpack only bootstrap overrides everything.

I have tried:

```
import './css/creative.css'
import './css/bootstrap.css'
```

And:

```
import './css/bootstrap.css'
import './css/creative.css'
```

Also tried to wrap app.js into a index.js and style the parent then the child like this:

- index.jsx : `import './css/bootstrap.css'`
- app.jsx : `import './css/creative.css'`

also tried the other way:

- index.jsx : `import './css/creative.css'`
- app.jsx : `import './css/bootstrap.css'`

But my custom style never overrides the bootstrap style.

This doesn't only happen for the HR but for example we have completely restyled the form inputs but they just appear as bootstraps default.

Comment: Are you sure that bootstrap is not imported in any other file in your project?

Comment: @CuriousSuperhero yes im sure

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/343r7r9o6m this works fine. Can you reproduce it on that site?

Comment: It depends on the order in which the stylesheets have been linked in the <head>...</head> tag. If you can provide a sample repo, I can help you resolve the issue.

Comment: You most likely should rotate `<link />` tags order on html page. Are you sure your own styling that you give has more power in matter of specifying elements. 

You should probably consider giving class names to your elements that you want to style your self and give more precise targets in css. eg. `hr.my-own-class` and your style will win over bootstraps default. In case you just declare many `hr` targets latest one wins. And this question is totally not React related btw.

Comment: @SuhasV This is a project under NDA so no I cant disclose any code.

Comment: @JimiPajala Yes I'm sure my style over rides fine as I have over 30 pages designed in html with it and they are all working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try importing Bootstrap from within your `creative.css` file? I think that will allow Webpack to get the order right, whereas when using `import` in JS to import CSS it doesn't define any strict order.

E.g.

index.js

```
import './css/creative.css'
```

creative.css

```
@import url('./bootstrap.css');
...your custom css...
```

Comment: Nice idea I didn't think of this I will totally give it a try and get back to you. I would have thought though as long as the async in not specified JS would load it in order.

Answer (score -2):

You can override bootstrap.css with creative.css using following step.

**Step 1.**
Set root id`<body id="bootstrap-overrides">`

**Step 2.** Do following changes in `creative.css`. You just need to set prefix to any CSS selector with your Id ("bootstrap-overrides") like below.

```
#bootstrap-overrides h1 
{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

Hope it will resolved your issue. Please try it.

Comment: Please try with !important. Previously some typing mistake from my end

Comment: I know about the `!important` but here we are not talking about 10 lines. the custom css is over a few thousand lines . furthermore this isnt how `!important` should be used

Comment: That is the opposite of what im looking for he is asking how to make sure bootstrap overrides the rest

Comment: @Mederic I just updated my answer and it's work as you need. Please check it. I glad if this will work for you.

Comment: @Mederic, did you check it.

Comment: As mentionned already I cant just hack my way renaming over 10 000 lines of css WildService solution was much cleaner